# change property of doc, if the view was requestet in CouchDB

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have a view where I get all customers and save them with curl as a json file. Now I would like to change a property of each document that where found in this view, how could I do this?

before I requested the view:

```
{
  "name": "somebody"
  "changed": true
}
```

after I requested the view:

```
{
  "name": "somebody"
  "changed": false
}
```

I tried to put it in my Design / View doc but that did not work:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type === "customer" && doc.changed === true) {
    doc.changed = false;
    emit(doc._id, doc);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to alter docs within a view.

A doc can be altered when it gets requested with the help of an update handler but thats limited to single doc scenarios.

The client side must be included. E.g. the response of the view can be altered client-side and send back to the `_bulk_docs` path. Another way could be to provide an update handler for altering `doc.changed` - then the client-side logic must send an empty POST to the update handler for every doc from the view response.